# Trouble with Python Flask routing: 404 Error for specific route

Tags: python, flask, web

I'm currently working on a web application using Flask, and I'm encountering a 404 error for a specific route. Here are the details:

python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

# The problematic route
@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render-template('contact.html')
```

Issue:
When I navigate to the "/contact" route, I get a 404 error. The other routes ("/" and "/about") work as expected. I've checked the templates and they seem fine.

Error Message:
The 404 error message I'm receiving is: "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server."

Attempts to Solve:
I've double-checked the route definition and the template file for the "contact" route. I've also restarted the Flask development server, but the issue persists.

Environment:

Python 3.8
Flask 2.0.1
Running on the local development server
Additional Context:
Is there anything specific I should be checking to troubleshoot this issue? I'm relatively new to Flask, so any guidance on debugging or common pitfalls would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo in the `render_template` directive for the contact route.

Comment: `return render-template('contact.html')` That should be an underscore, not a dash.